# Solubility of amlodipine besylate

Tags: drugs

In *European Pharmacopoeia*, the drug amlodipine besylate is characterised as slightly soluble in water and freely soluble in methanol (additionally, sparingly soluble in anhydrous ethanol and slightly soluble in 2-propanol). Why is this? Both water and methanol are polar protic solvents.

Comment: There is big difference between water and methanol. Also what is this "freely soluble" supposed to mean? Sounds like overstatement.

Comment: I understand water and methanol are different, however both are polar protic solvents, so I'm not sure why a substance would have such different solubilities between the two. 
In regards to "freely soluble" that is a quote from monograph in the European Pharmacopoeia.

Comment: That's the problem what this difference is. I doubt it's as big as you seem to think. Finding more accurate info may be difficult, though.

Comment: Right that's what I'm having a hard time with. I'm a pharmacy student, and in an upcoming exam, will probably be asked to judge the solubility of a drug on the basis of it's structure. I picked this example as I can't figure out why it would be different. I've referenced a couple of organic chemistry texts and medicinal chemistry texts, and not come up with much.

Answer (score 1):

According to OP, the monograph in the European Pharmacopoeia says:

> the drug amlodipine besylate is characterized as slightly soluble in water and freely soluble in methanol (additionally, sparingly soluble in anhydrous ethanol and slightly soluble in 2-propanol).

Theory and application of solubility Parameters are at least beyond my scope. Yet, above excerpts doesn't make any sense. If amlodipine besylate (AMB) is slightly soluble in water and freely soluble in methanol, to my common knowledge in organic chemistry, it should be at least moderately (not sparingly) soluble in absolute ethanol based on increasing organic nature from methanol to ethanol (see [my answer in this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111952/miscibility-of-hexane-and-ethanol-anhydrous-vs-96) to understand one of parameters in solubility theory). Thus, I'd say OP might have misunderstood the facts given in European Pharmacopoeia. I haven't seen this monograph, but I assume it might be talking about different salts of amlodipine (e.g., amlodipine acetate).

I have tried to find some reliable data in literature, but it wasn't as successful as I expected. Yet again, different publications give different values for solubility. For example, Ref.1 gives Experimental Mole Fraction Solubility $(X_{m,T}^{Exp})$ of AMB at $\pu{30 ^\circ C}$ as $2.56 \times 10^{-5}$ and $6.20 \times 10^{-7}$ in absolute ethanol and water, respectively. According to this results, AMB dissolves highly in absolute ethanol compared to that in water (definitely not slightly in water to sparingly in absolute ethanol). Note that, in Ref.2, even though it is from the same research group, $(X_{m,T}^{Exp})$ of AMB in water at $\pu{30 ^\circ C}$ as $6.30 \times 10^{-5}$ $(\pu{0.0051 M})$.

When the counter ion is changed from besylate to acetate, the solubility has changed dramatically (Ref.3):

$(X_{m,T}^{Exp})$ of amlodipine acetate at $\pu{30 ^\circ C}$: $4.370 \times 10^{-3}$ (in methanol); $6.951 \times 10^{-3}$ (in ethanol); and $7.737 \times 10^{-3}$ (in 2-propanol).

As I expected, the solubility has increased with the increasing organic nature of the protic solvent.

---

**References:**

1. Faroukh Sardari and Abolghasem Jouyban, "Solubility of 3-Ethyl-5-methyl-(4*RS*)-2-((2-aminoethoxy)methyl)-4-(2-chlorophenyl)-1,4-dihydro-6-methyl-3,5-pyridinedicarboxylate Monobenzenesulfonate (Amlodipine Besylate) in Ethanol + Water and Propane-1,2-diol + Water Mixtures at Various Temperatures," *J. Chem. Eng. Data* **2012**, *57(10)*, 2848–2854 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/je3005672).
2. Elmira Behboudi, Jafar Soleymani, Fleming Martinez, and Abolghasem Jouyban, "Solubility of amlodipine besylate in binary mixtures of polyethylene glycol 400 + water at various temperatures: Measurement and modelling," *Journal of Molecular Liquids* **2022**, *347*, 118394 (10 pages) (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molliq.2021.118394).
3. Chao Cheng, Yang Cong, Cunbin Du, Jian wang, Ganbing Yao, and Hongkun Zhao, "Solubility determination and thermodynamic models for dehydroepiandrosterone acetate in mixed solvents of (ethyl acetate + methanol), (ethyl acetate + ethanol) and (ethyl acetate + isopropanol)," *The Journal of Chemical Thermodynamics* **2016**, *101*, 372-379 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jct.2016.06.014).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't misquote the monograph, below is a direct copy paste from Ph. Eur. 11.2. 

CHARACTERS
Appearance: white or almost white powder.

Solubility: slightly soluble in water, freely soluble in methanol, sparingly soluble in anhydrous ethanol, slightly soluble in 2-propanol.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult you. But people make mistakes (including me). In that case, may be European Pharmacopoeia did it here. :-)

Comment: No insult taken! As a student, I understand the mistakes lies much more often with me. In a few weeks I have an exam in Arzneistoffanalytik (drug analysis) and looking at the past exams, these sorts of solubility questions have come up often. Unfortunately, the instructor is not exactly the most approachable, so I'm trying to figure it out.